# ng-quill text editor only updates once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, quill

I have an angular app and I am using [ngQuill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngQuill)

The basic directive is implemented by injecting it into your app and using the tag in your HTML:

```
<ng-quill-editor class="" ng-model="document.doc" toolbar="true" link-tooltip="true" image-tooltip="true" toolbar-entries="font size bold list bullet italic underline strike align color background link image" editor-required="true" required="" error-class="input-error"></ng-quill-editor>
```

In my app I have a modal which allows the user to select a document to load from a `select`.  Everything works great the first time.  If I try to load a different document however, ngQuill refuses to update.  The data is getting pushed to other bindings, but not ngQuill.  I did a test to see if the binding hooked to ngQuill is actually getting the data and **it is**, but ngQuill never updates.

I thought maybe it just needed a $digest, but I tried $timeout and $apply and nothing.  It's almost like it's losing the binding.  Any suggestions?

If you check out **[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zK4cqDvr8mlZ5Tmx1IPt?p=preview)** you can see the issue.  Click one button and then the other - the first one will load correctly, but then after that only the title changes.

The documentation also has the following, but I am not sure that it is relevant or how to even use it:

> if you use it in a form and you are resetting it via $setPristine() -> you have to set editor.setHTML('') -> it will add the error class only, if the model has ng-dirty class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the two-way binding to work consistently I had to add a $watch function in the `link` of the directive in the ng-quill.js file.

Basically all it does is watch to see if I change the ng-model binding attached to the directive in the view, and then compares it against what the editor currently has stored inside the directive.  If the two are not equal, it replaces the internal document with the external one.

I also added a condition so that if I set the external ng-model binding to undefined it will clear the ng-quill document as well.

Here is the function:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return ngModel.$viewValue;
  }, 
  function (newText) {
    if (newText && newText !== editor.getHTML()) {
      editor.setHTML(newText);
    }
    if (newText === undefined) {
      editor.setHTML('');
    }
  }
);
```